# Is it possible to integrate Spree with MongoDB (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, spree

I used Spree in my project by using following Link,
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

And i tried to use mongoDB with Spree in my Rails Application. Its not working for me.
Is it possible to use mongoDB with Spree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Ryan Bigg, no, it's not possible. (source: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1971)

Comment: oh, I made such a mistake. fixed!